# How can i get effect shown in video attached in link below in unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I want to move light with mesh of game object and if mesh divide further into different parts so lights should automatically travels on that path also... as show in video linked below. Any Help....???

[Video Url](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3QkjSFxmpLtNk50TjF2ekFtbUU/view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always write a shader, but that would be an overkill just show an effect. IMHO the better approach would be to create an animation of this effect in any of the modelling software.

- Create These models in your modelling software.
- Make individual animations for each mesh.
- Trigger Those animations whenever you want
  such effect.